# Попарная группировка чисел в строке

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Задачка на поиск подстроки и замену в python'e.
Имеется регулярное выражение, результатом использования которого получается строка:

```
string = "1.1 1.2, 2.1 2.2, 3.1 3.2, ..."
```

необходимо ее превратить в:

```
string = "[1.1,1.2],[2.1,2.2],[3.1,3.2],..."
```

Подскажите, как грамотнее ее решить.

Может надо использовать `re.sub(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = "1.1 1.2, 2.1 2.2, 3.1 3.2"
print ','.join(['[%s]' % ','.join(x.split(' ')) for x in s.split(", ")])
```

Comment: А если будет string = "(((1.1 1.2, 2.1 2.2), 3.1 3.2, ..."
И нужно каждую пару чисел взять в квадратные скобки и разделить запятой вместо пробела, а круглые так и оставить